# Working with nested lists in Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

```
list_ = [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
```

What is the Pythonic way of taking sum of ordered pairs from inner tuples and multiplying the sums? For the above example:

```
(1 + 3) * (2 + 4) = 24
```

Comment: What happens if there are 3 tuples: `list_ = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]`?

Comment: @erip `(1+3+5) * (2+4+6) = 108`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For example:

```
import operator as op
import functools
functools.reduce(op.mul, (sum(x) for x in zip(*list_)))
```

works for any length of the initial array as well as of the inner tuples.

Another solution using [numpy](http://www.numpy.org):

```
import numpy as np
np.array(list_).sum(0).prod()
```

Comment: @PeterWood Sure, why not?

Comment: @erip because `reduce` was removed from python 3: https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins

Comment: @eumiro just to add to the available options: rather than importing `operator.mul`, `lambda x, y: x * y` works fine also. Although really there is nothing wrong with `op.mul` to begin with :).

Comment: @kazemakase: thank you for the `reduce` info - I have updated the answer.

Comment: @PeterWood - thank you your for the generator expression idea.

Comment: @N.Wouda `op.mul` will be faster and avoids having to use `lambda` (which looks bad imo)

Comment: The first solution is great however I'd use `map(sum, ...)`, this is on Python 3 so it would return an iterator. So: `functools.reduce(op.mul, map(sum, zip(*list_)))`

Comment: What if the initial list is empty? It raises a `TypeError`.

Comment: @jamylak I got 0.033 +/- 0.002 for a `timeit` on `op.mul`, and 0.034 +/- 0.003 for a `lambda` expression. So, the claim that _`op.mul` will be faster_ is dubious at best. With regard to avoiding having to use `lambda`, well, that's just personal taste.

Comment: @eumiro Considering your first solution, how would you change it, say, to exclude the last item in every nested list. For example: `[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)] --> (1 + 4 +7) * (2 + 5 +8) = 180`

Comment: @blackened: how about `functools.reduce(op.mul, (sum(x) for x in list(zip(*list_))[:-1]))` ?

Comment: @eumiro Thanks. Is there an alternative. (Perhaps because one would like to exclude, say, the nth and the mth item.)

Comment: @blackened - this is probably too much for a one-liner. Write a readable multi-line code.

Comment: @N.Wouda I'd need to see timings first

Answer (score 0):

If the lists are small as is implied, I feel that using `operator` and `itertools` for something like this is applying a sledgehammer to a nut. Likewise `numpy`. What is wrong with pure Python?

```
result = 1
for s in [ sum(x) for x in zip( *list_) ]: 
  result *= s
```

(although it would be a lot nicer if pure 
Python had a `product` built-in as well as `sum` ). Also if you are specifically dealing only with pairs of 2-tuples then any form of iteration is a sledgehammer. Just code

```
result = (list_[0][0]+list_[1][0] )*( list_[0][1]+list_[1][1])
```

Comment: You could also argue that using `zip(*)` is a sledgehammer when you could just do it with pure python. Using `reduce` simply does the same thing your code does but more concise

Comment: Yes, `reduce` is a  built-in as well as `zip` so its just that I  personally find this way easier to read.

Comment: Actually my previous is wrong. `zip` is a Python 3 built-in but `reduce` is not, so my way is Python 2/3 agnostic.